# Can I convert any string to float without losing precision in Python?

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm parsing some price information from an API, do I need to worry about losing precision if I just do `price = float(price_str)`?

Or do I have to use `decimal.Decimal` to make sure the original value is parsed?

Comment: Can you show that what's `price_str` look like?

Comment: How long is the string? `float()` can only parse up to 17 numbers

Comment: i would have used `decimal.Decimal`.  why do you not want to?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: I'm not sure what you mean.  The input to `float` can have as many digits as you like, and they're all taken into account when determining which way to round.  Compare the results of `float('8000000000000000.5')` and `float('8000000000000000.500000000001')`, for example.

Comment: @satoru read my update about json and Decimal class ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Decimal class when working with currency!
Why? Let's see this dummy example:

```
float('0.2') + float('0.1')
```

Result: `0.30000000000000004`

With Decimal instead:

```
Decimal('0.2') + Decimal('0.1')
```

Result: `Decimal('0.3')`

**UPDATE:**

if you are using third party API with json format, you can use Decimal to automatically parse floating numbers automatically: see my blog post: http://www.daveoncode.com/2014/10/21/python-reading-numbers-from-json-without-loss-of-precision-using-decimal-class-for-data-processing/

Answer (score 3):

Prices should be decimal, floats often introduce rounding errors which will give you headaches in the long run. Example:

```
In [1]: 3*0.1
Out[1]: 0.30000000000000004
```